# How to generate OpenAPI 3 documentation from protobuf files

Tags: protocol-buffers, openapi

I have an API generated from protobuf, and I would like to generate documentation conforming to the OpenAPI 3 spec. I've looked at a number of utilities but I haven't found a combination that works.

Does anyone know of a path from protobuf to OpenAPI 3 that I can follow?

Answer (score 6):

I searched for the answer recently and found this package:
[protobuf2swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobuf2swagger)
It can be run in CLI with a js config file required. This packaged solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like **[protoc-gen-openapi](https://github.com/google/gnostic/tree/master/cmd/protoc-gen-openapi) app**, from `gnostic`, is what you were looking for. But it seems abandoned and not working.

*Have no idea if it works.*

Comment: Some updates about this here: https://github.com/google/gnostic/issues/257

Comment: It moved to https://github.com/google/gnostic/tree/master/cmd/protoc-gen-openapi now

Comment: It doesn't work. Take a look at the "protos" in their examples. They all use some asinine syntax. If you use a normal protobuf syntax, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Google has a [repository](https://github.com/googleapis/gnostic) on GitHub to do exactly that. It contains examples for OpenAPI v3 (and v2) on how the equivalent protobuf code should look like.

Here is a [medium article](https://medium.com/@amsokol.com/tutorial-how-to-develop-go-grpc-microservice-with-http-rest-endpoint-middleware-kubernetes-daebb36a97e9) that explains end to end gRPC + HTTP (using protobuf and swagger respectively) server implementation and documentation, in a step by step fashion. It is an OpenAPI v2 example, but similar concepts apply to OpenAPI v3.

There are other [repositories](https://github.com/nytimes/openapi2proto) that can do the same, but I would recommend to use the source code that is actually coming from the very source. :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first and last links are for converting OAS to protos/gRPC, not protos/gRPC to OAS. The middle link is an article about https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway which does to gRPC to OAS, though it's OAS 2.

Comment: I wish there is a way to integrate grpc-gateway in Quarkus /java project.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these links answer the OP's question, which is very specific (I'm also looking for an answer.)